# facebook access_token clarification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have an facebook app that is supposed to send some notifications to its users. This will be done by a cron, and I found two ways to get the `access_token` needed to perform this action:

1.

```
$app_token = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
    "client_id=" . appid .
    "&client_secret=" . secret .
    "&grant_type=client_credentials");
```

2.

```
$fb = new Facebook(array('appId' => appid, 'secret' => secret, 'cookie' => true));
$app_token = $fb->getAccessToken(),
```

I can understand that there are two different ways to get the `access_token`, but **why do I get different values** from the two methods? [both work just the same as far as I've noticed]

I want to know what the diference is and what is the best method to get an `access_token`.

Comment: I guess each time you make a request you'll get different token, right? The above two ways fire two different calls and so its returning a different token. i might be wrong but that's my perception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firing at the oauth endpoint will always give you the long lived token, which is different than the short lived one.

Answer (score 0):

I think second option is good. Because in future Facebook may change the URL to get access token. But in second option you are using oAuth and it is more secured. You may need to change SDK that you use. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

The main different is, the second one does not require http request  to get the apps access token, just concate together both client id and client secret with '|'.

Example client_id 'abc' and client_secret 'def', then 'abc|def' is ready to use when you call https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=abc|def